# Apache server in port number 80

Tags: apache, port

Though the question asked seems to be very ridiculous but I am practically facing this and left with no option but to ask it.
In httpd.conf file whenever I give port no other than 80 it works fine but if I give port no 80 after some time or may be from beginning it stops working means I am not able to get the desired web page though 
when I try netstat -ano it shows that apache server is running on port no 80.

previously IIS7 was working on port no 80.I stoped the process.

Answer (score 0):

Locate your apache config and search for:

```
Listen 80
```

change 80 to your desired port

Next you may want to change the vHost setting. Find whereever your vhost settings are located (mostly conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf) and locate something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@domain.tld
    DocumentRoot "path/to/my/document/root" 
    ServerName subdomain.domain.tld
    ErrorLog "path/to/my/error/log/domain.error.log" 
    CustomLog "path/to/my/access/log/domain.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

change the 80 here again to your desired port. Restart your apache.
If youre working on unix:

```
service apache22 start
service apache22 stop
```

(commands for apache 2.2)

on windows:

```
net stop apache2.2
net start apache2.2
```

(commands for apache 2.2)

Greetings

(make sure your firewall doesnt block your desired port and its not used by another programm. For additional help you should always check your error logs.